# Flash Messages in Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug, passport.js

Following this example: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local and everything works fine except the Flash messages part.

I have changed the view engine to Jade instead of EJS but I just can't seem to get the flash messages to show.

The code provided in the ejs view is:

```
<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
<% } %>
```

and I would have thought that I could do this instead for Jade:

```
if #{message}
  p message
```

or even:

```
if message
  p message
```

but no success. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Note** I have included all the necessary libraries as per the tutorial

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I used flashes in Jade...

```
-if(messages)
        div#note #{messages}
```

And use this to render your view, passing the messages var to your view

```
req.flash('info', "Credenciales invalidas, intente nuevamente");
res.render('index', {messages: req.flash('info')});
```

That works for me

Comment: The flash message is set in the Passportjs strategy and then I'm using the FailureRedirect - will the flash message still be available?

Comment: It doesn't work - so how do i render the login page with the FailureRedirect - will I need to use a custom callback?

Comment: I'm no expert at passport but I guess using a custom callback would do it

Comment: @tommyd456, I tried the above jade code and it works even if the FailureRedirect to "login" page. you need to put `res.render('login', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });` to your route `app.get('/login')` and use `-if(messages.length)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and used a custom callback like so:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            if (!user) { return res.render('login', {message: req.flash('loginMessage')}); }
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (as commented by @Xianlin). Routes:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
});

app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/profile',
    failureRedirect : '/login',
    failureFlash : true
}));
```

Return the required error message using Passport:

```
return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'That email address does not exist'));
```

And finally in Jade:

```
if (message.length > 0)
  #alert
    p= message
```

Hope this helps!